# Custom directory structure in Eclipse new project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse , whenever I create a new Java project, it's structure will be as follows.

```
Project
   |
   |    
   -------- src
   |
   -------- bin
```

src is a Source Folder. bin is the output folder. I need to have some more normal folders like lib,conf,docs,etc in all my projects. Now I am creating every folder manually by myself whenever I create a new project.Is there anyway or plugin available to create additional folders(Not Source folders) in Eclipse when creating new project? I am not interested in plugin-development. Any readily available plugin would be nice.

Comment: You mean defining a new project model? So that every time you create a new project you get the directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no plugin for that. If you don't want to keep a skeleton folder to copy over, I suggest you try writing or searching the web for a Maven project archetype. Writing an archetype is quite straightforward, have a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/index.html). You will have to install Maven plugin in Eclipse and, upon creation of a new Maven project, you will be offered to use such a template.

Comment: @stefano Sanfilippo +1 for great idea, is same possible by creating new plugins ?, I am writting new plugin from scratch. If its possible to extends Java project then it will be more helpful..

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but if you're in the same workspace, why not create a default, empty project with the folders you want and then copy-and-paste into newly-created projects?