# JavaFX - POM, UI & Controllers per device

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, pom.xml, object-model

i am new in Java, and begginer in programming (simple bash scripting i can do).

I know there are commonly used POMs, but i want to avoid junk in project and create custom POM. As my English isn't perfect, ill illustrate it.

- SRC/Main
- - Core // where things are going
- - - Main package files, every job is done here
- - Android // fxml, css, general UI and controllers
- - - include core
- - PC // as above
- - - include core
- - web // as above
- - - include core
- SRC/Test
- - // as above but #testing
- BIN
- - Android
- - PC
- - Web

Separate platforms that have different display, input, destiny (run in background on android, notifications). It's why title is JavaFX. Compiling different resources for different platform. Where core has possibility to work in commandline.

Goal is to test, build, compile all per-platform packages, using one command. Something like project with subprojects. Maybe i am crazy but i think it should be possible via gradle.

Maybe i am dreaming, so i am asking. It's a good idea? Someone practices this project structure? It's possible to still have automotion like in Maven/Ant/Gradle with this layout? If you know any tutorial related to this POM, i'll be happy to see any link.

---

Related, but not explaining:

- [Custom directory structure in Eclipse new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415099/custom-directory-structure-in-eclipse-new-project)
- [How to make java packages](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs2102/b12/Assignments/making-packages.html)
- [Android Project View](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/#ProjectView)
- [Android Project Structure](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Organizing-your-Source-Files#android-folder-structure)
- [CDEJ Project Folder Structure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8S5A_6.2.0/com.ibm.curam.content.doc/WebClientReference/r_WEBCREF_Development1ProjectFolderStructure1.html)
- [Maven - creating archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html)

Resources are only part of goal. If you want i can split this question into few small questions.